# Is there a way to use PHPExcel in view of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, phpexcel

[PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is a library to generate MS Excel file using PHP (and so far the best one I have used in supporting Chinese output). It works fine in Laravel. However, unlike libraries for generating email or PDF files, in PHPExcel (and many other libraries used for generating Excel file) the file can only be generated by calling PHP functions instead of converting HTML into Excel, so the code has to be put in controller / classes.

I feel a little uncomfortable to put codes that mainly for views into controller, and it is a group project so readability is also a concern. Is there a way I can put the code generating Excel file into view in Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install "maatwebsite/excel" package, and then you can use the functionality of PHPExcel. Go: [here](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) to get basic information regarding package installation, and [here](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) to get detail tutorial, on how to use this package.

See, if that helps.

Comment: It looks attractive, but  as the exporting as Excel function is an extra function added to an old project that used Laravel 4.0, and the server is running PHP 5.3.13. The library needs at least Larave. 4.1 and PHP 5.3.7. Too bad this is not a solution to my situation.

Good answer though. Will consider using this in later projects.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 allows you to place your classes anywhere in the `app` folder, given the appropriate PSR-4 compliance.

Therefore, you can create a class which is solely responsible for containing all codes pertaining to the creation of your Excel files.

Then you can call the method, from your controller whenever appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as the exporting as Excel function is an extra function added to an old project that used Laravel 4. Considering that the code is actually working, it would be too much to change to Laravel 5 just for putting the code in view.

Comment: Laravel 4, too supports autoloading through PSR-0: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/46/using-a-psr-0-directory-structure